# Excel Data Model interpreting dates wrongly

Tags: excel, date, datamodel

I'm pulling in data from a cube into the Excel Data Model.  The Data Model appears to be expecting one format and getting another:

- The actual symptom is a very old one that I’ve seen for many years.

  - Server sends 06/13/2017 (MM/DD/YY), Data Model knows there can’t be 30 months in a year, so swaps it automatically to 13/06/2017.
  - Server sends 06/12/2017 (MM/DD/YY), Data Model has no issue with 12 months, so does not swap MM/DD around, resulting in 6th December rather than 12th June.

How do I resolve this as I have half the dates are correct (ones where the day>12) and the other half are not.

Answer (score 0):

I would convert the date to 'YYYY-MM-DD' on the server side.